# Why does this DIV have a width larger than the contained SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox

This is a stripped-down version of a problem I am having. The SVG is scaling down correctly to fit the fixed height of `container2`, but `container3` for some reason has a width of 150.

Removing `container1` makes `container3` fit tightly to the SVG, as does removing the `flex` property of `container1`. Setting any width value on the SVG makes the size of `container3` double, and at this point I really just have no idea what's going on.

The described behavior was when testing on Chrome

```css
#container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 5px;
}

#container2 {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 35px;
}

#container3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='container1'>
  <div id='container2'>
    <div id='container3'>
      <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 100 100' height='100%' stroke='white'>
        <circle cx='50' cy='50' r='35' fill-opacity='0' />
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why is `container3` behaving this way, and what style changes do I need to make so that `container3` fits tightly to my SVG without changing the overall layout?

Comment: Which browser are you testing on? Your code renders differently on Chrome / Edge vs Firefox. https://jsfiddle.net/4zqecvg3/

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin I ran mine on Chrome. I didn't realize it renders differently on Chrome, so I'll edit the question. But if you say its different between browsers, then maybe it's not a question worth asking in the first place.

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is. Some more details may be helpful.

Comment: Are you sure you had the `viewBox` attribute? Your description of the issue sounds like what should happen in case the svg doesn't have a defined aspect-ratio and just a height attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand clearly what is the problem here. But when you give some width to your container3 it will fix your display problem.

```
#container3 {
  display:block; //it is not neccessary for your code but I think it should have some display code
  width: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
```